# Mod rewrite doesn't work with some persian words

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website in which I need to use `mod_rewrite` to pass some Persian words to my php file and then catch them in php and do the rest of the processes.
I've done the `.htaccess` file configurations like those on the web, but the problem is that it works on some words and doesn't work on some others.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cat/thumb/([^.]+\.jpg)$ getpic.php?name=$1&thumb=true [L,QSA,NC,NE]
RewriteRule ^cat/([^.]+\.jpg)$ getpic.php?name=$1&thumb=false [L,QSA,NC,NE]
RewriteRule ^cat(.*)$ cats.php?fn=$1 [NC,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ job.php?j_id=$1 [NC,L,NE]
```

The one that's problematic is the third rule.

For example it works on these URLs:

```
http://kodaa.com:81/jobs/cat/-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%B9%DA%A9%D8%B3

http://kodaa.com:81/jobs/cat/-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%B9%DA%A9%D8%B3-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C%20%D8%A2%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86
```

but doesn't work on these ones:

```
http://kodaa.com:81/jobs/cat/-%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%20%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C

http://kodaa.com:81/jobs/cat/-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%87
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this rule: `RewriteRule ^cat(.*)$ cats.php?fn=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava still not working :( , says: The requested URL /jobs/cat/-Ø±Ø§ÛŒØ§Ù†Ù‡-Ø¨Ø±Ù†Ø§Ù…Ù‡ Ù†ÙˆÛŒØ³ÛŒ was not found on this server.

Comment: What is original URL you entered in browser?